# Is this dependency injection in node.js or some other common pattern?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, coffeescript

I'm working with a team that uses coffeescript along with node.js.  They have a lot of code that uses the following structure, something I haven't seen before:

```
   locationNames: ['address', 'state', 'neighborhood', (cb, resp) ->
      locationName = null
      commonName = null
      if resp.neighborhood
        locationName = resp.neighborhood.commonName
        commonName = resp.neighborhood.commonName
      else if resp.state
        locationName = resp.state.Name
        commonName = resp.state.commonName
      else
        locationName = resp.address.getSafeShortName()
        commonName = resp.address.getSafeShortName()   
      cb null, {
        commonName: commonName
        locationName: locationName
      }
    ]
```

It seems like everything goes in an array, including what appear to be depedencies (`address`,`state`,`neighborhood`) that are somehow tied to the response object.

Is this a form of dependency injection in node.js, or a well-known convention of some sort?

Comment: I think you're on the money about it being dependency injection, as Angular.js on the frontend allows a very similar syntax for doing DI. That said, I've never encountered this exact structure.

Comment: @JoeClay Yes this looks extremely similar to a Angular Service definition, definitely looks like a DI pattern of some sort.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen.  I'm just not sure how they're injecting this, looking over their codebase-- I wasn't sure if there was some form of DI built into node, or available as an npm package?

Comment: Ok, I found out what's going on.  This team uses the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#auto) library to determine call order-- and with the `auto` setting (which they use) you need to tell your functions which other ones need to have completed first.